# SQLite: update then select the same row in the same transaction

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database and open it with these pargama:

```
PRAGMA SYNCHRONOUS = OFF
PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE = MEMORY
PRAGMA TEMP_STORE = MEMORY
```

Problem is: I have to begin transaction, update some fields in a row then select whole row after that and then commit the transaction. I aware that new updated fields are not reflated changes and it brings me problems.
What do I do wrong here? Please help!

Comment: I am using C# .Net 2.0 System.Data.SQLite

Comment: All changes are visible immediately. Or are you using a different connection?

Comment: No, I am using the same connection. Most of case, app run smoothly, but some times has problems. After a while checking carefully, I doubt that problems reside in sqlite mechanism.

Comment: in a transaction, the client that's making the transaction can see the updated data. If that's not happening include more information in your post.